# What is the command line for opening an Outlook Appointment with attendees and location set?

Tags: command-line, outlook, appointment

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.appointment /m "info@xxx.com&cc=admin@xxx.com&subject=Hello World&body=Hi"
```

The above command opens an appointment as following:
[image]

Is it possible to show the email *To...* field by default without clicking the button *Invite Attendees*, and setting some default value for *Location* field by the command line?
[image]

If possible, how to make the changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I can find is to create a .oft template from a meeting invitation with the location saved.  Then call using the /t switch:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /t "C:\Users\Me\Documents\MeetingInviteTemplate.oft"

Answer (score 0):

This command line works, the only issue is that it doesn't show you the email address but when you click on the attendees, you will see that the email address is already added in the invitation.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE"/c ipm.appointment /m "info@domain.nl ?subject=call to tel$n &body=Can we meet please call to tel:$n"
```

The `$n` parameters, I use them to copy the telephone number into the appointment during a call with myApps from innovaphone.